# Javascript keyboard/mouse listener outside browser

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, event-listener, mouselistener

I want to make a javascript "auto-clicker" to automate some tasks. I want to be able to record a sequence of clicks and possibly keyboard entries and then run that sequence.

Is there any node-package or library that I can use to listen to mouse and keyboard events outside a browser?
All I can seem to find are implementations for browser activity, but I want to be able to run this on anything.

I made an implementation of this but in Python, but I want to improve my javascript this time.

Comment: If you want to do this with Javascript, easiest method by far IMO would be to do it with a userscript, *inside* a browser. Outside a userscript, might be able to do it with Puppeteer or something similar, but that makes things a whole lot more complicated, especially if you're not experienced with JS yet

Comment: Aren't those for in-browser usage? I'd like to write a small script/code that I can run in say Word or Excel or something. I'd like to be able to run this script in a terminal and use it on Word or Excel or something. I can automate the sequence with something like puppeteer or robot.js but I need something that can listen for mouse and keyboard events on a "system-level" so to speak.

Comment: I'm quite doubtful that the scripting options available to Word or Excel are anywhere near suited for web scraping. It might not be impossible, but it's not the right kind of tool for the job at all

Comment: Exactly. So I'm just wondering if anyone knows any library or node-package or similar or how to implement a desktop/"system"-level mouse/keyboard event listener.

Comment: @DannyBoy Why wouldn't you just use the JavaScript interface built into Word and Excel?  No need to simulate clicks or anything.

Comment: I mean, Word and Excel were just examples to illustrate the desire to use this outside a browser environment so to speak. In places where I can not interface with the program I want to automate. In essence, I want to create a program or script that just uses the cursor position on the screen which I can do in robot.js. But I can't find anything that listens to "computer-level" mouse and keyboard events.